# Infopath Submit Button Rules not saving

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

I'm using InfoPath 2010 and I have 27 data connections programmed into the Form Submit button.  I am creating rules to send the form using one of these 27 connections based on a Work Location drop-down list that the user has selected in the form.  I click on the Submit Button and create an action rule for each of these data connections.  When done, I save the form and close it but when I re-open the form and click on the Submit button, all of the rules I created are gone.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.  When opening up the button properties I had selected "Submit" instead of "Rules and Custom Code" which solved the problem.  I thought I had done that yesterday but for some reason it didn't seem to work right.  I was able to put in the rules today and they saved.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your SAVING the form and then OPENING it again from the site. You need to PUBLISH the form to the site in order for your changes to become visible in SharePoint. 
Here's some good reading on the topic. 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Publish-a-form-template-to-a-server-running-InfoPath-Forms-Services-8a56dc3f-2d51-48df-a134-14022b2bfd82

Comment: Thank you for your response but I don't that that's it.  I have not yet published this form or the others I am developing.  I am still in the design stage.  I created similar forms for another company a couple of years ago on an earlier InfoPath version and creating rules worked fine.  There seems to be something different about the 2010 version that is causing me problems.